# Printing of combining diacritical marks on esc/pos printer with windows-1258 codepage

Tags: printing, character-encoding, escpos

I bought a thermal receipt printer from Amazon which supports Windows-1258 for Vietnamese.  But unlike Unicode with precomposed characters, most Vietnamese symbols are not present in the 1258 codepage.  For example, Ả ả Ã ã Ạ ạ Ắ ắ Ằ ằ Ẳ ẳ Ẵ ẵ Ặ ặ Ấ ấ Ầ ầ Ẩ ẩ Ẫ ẫ Ậ ậ Ẻ ẻ Ẽ ẽ Ẹ ẹ Ế ế Ề ề Ể ể Ễ ễ Ệ ệ, etc.

How can I print these non-precomposed characters using the ESC/POS commands?  I was thinking to move the printing cursor backward and then superimposing/overlaying the accent on top. But even though this maybe possible it seems to be too tedious.  I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use user-defined characters which are defined using the ESC & command.  The full description of the command is found in the ESC/POS Application Programming Guide (APG).

Once defined, switch to user defined character set whenever you want to print such a character.

Also not that not all ESC/POS printers support user-defined characters, e.g. the Epson TM-T60 does not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @marc-balmer.

Correct me if I am wrong. Say I want to define the character Ự and assign it to code point 32. Am I correct by sending

ESC & 3 32 [the bitmap pattern of Ự.......]

When I need to use it, I will enable user define character by sending

ESC & 1 // to enable user define character

Once I print it,

ESC & 0  // to cancel user define